# Ultralytics Yolo - get the amount of objects count of a specified class

Tags: python, yolo

I'm new to Ultralytics YOLO. I'm trying to get the total objects (of a specified class "Person") identified in a single image.

This is the code:

```
import json
from ultralytics import YOLO

def test_yolo(image_path):
    model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')
    results = model(image_path)
    return results


if __name__ == "__main__":
    results = test_yolo('/home/myuser/test/yolo/data/persone.jpg')
    count = 0
    results_array = json.loads(results[0].tojson())
    
    
    
    for result in results_array:
        if result["name"] == "person":
            count = count +1
    
    
    print("Persons: ", count)
```

With this method, results are converted to a  Json  array with ".json()" method and the Json array is converted to a python list of dicts with "json.loads()".
But I'm sure it's not the right way to do the task.

This is the output:

image 1/1 /home/myuser/test/yolo/data/persone.jpg: 384x640 6 persons, 1 tie, 63.5ms
Speed: 2.2ms preprocess, 63.5ms inference, 1.1ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 384, 640)

Persons:  6

As you can see, it prints in the first line the number of objects recognized, and this means that Yolo already has the objects count. How I can access this counter without using my (inefficient) code?